# Should I pass an object into a constructor, or instantiate in class?

Tags: object-oriented, unit-testing, configuration

Consider these two examples:

#### Passing an object to a constructor

```
class ExampleA
{
  private $config;
  public function __construct($config)
  {
     $this->config = $config;
  }
}
$config = new Config;
$exampleA = new ExampleA($config);
```

#### Instantiating a class

```
class ExampleB
{
  private $config;
  public function __construct()
  {
     $this->config = new Config;
  }
}
$exampleA = new ExampleA();
```

Which is the correct way to handle adding an object as a property? When should I use one over the other? Does unit testing affect what I should use?

Comment: Might this be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions ?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - this isn't suitable for Code Review.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the first one will give you the ability to create a `config` object elsewhere and pass it to `ExampleA`. If you need Dependency Injection, this can be a good thing because you can ensure that all intances share the same object.

On the other hand, maybe your `ExampleA` *requires* a new and clean `config` object so there could be cases where the second example is more appropriate, such as cases where each instance could potentially have a different configuration.

Comment: So, A is good for unit testing, B is good for other circumstances... why not have both? I often have two constructors, one for manual DI, one for normal usage (I use Unity for DI, which will generate constructors to fulfill its DI requirements).

Comment: @EdWoodcock it's not really about unit testing vs other circumstances. The object either requires the dependency from outside or it manages it on the inside. Never both/either.

Answer (score 9):

Do not forget about testability!

Usually if the behavior of `Example` class depends on the config you want to be able to test it without saving/modifying the internal state of the class instance (i.e. you would want to have simple tests for happy path and for wrong config without modifying the property/memeber of `Example` class).

Therefore I would go with first option of `ExampleA`

Comment: Thats why I mentioned testing - thanks for adding that :)

Answer (score 6):

If the object has responsibility for *managing the lifetime* of the dependency, then it's OK to create the object in the constructor (and dispose it in the destructor).*

If the object is not responsible for managing the lifetime of the dependency, it should be passed into the constructor and managed from outside (eg by an IoC container).

In this case I don't think your ClassA should take responsibility for creating $config, unless it is also responsible for disposing it, or if the config is unique for each instance of ClassA.

*To aid in testability, the constructor could take a reference to a factory class/method to construct the dependency in its constructor, increasing cohesion and testability.

```
//Object which manages the lifetime of its dependency (C#):
public class ClassA : IDisposable
{
    public Config Config { get; private set; }

    public ClassA()
    {
        this.Config = new Config(); // Tightly coupled to Config class...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Config.Dispose();
    }
}

// Object which does not manage its dependency:
public class ClassA
{
    public Config Config { get; set; }

    public ClassA(Config config) // dependency may be injected...
    {
        this.Config = config;
    }
}

// Object which manages its dependency in a testable way:
public class ClassA : IDisposable
{
    public Config Config { get; private set; }

    public ClassA(IConfigFactory configFactory) // dependency may be mocked...
    {
        this.Config = configFactory.BuildConfig();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Config.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this exact same discussion with our architecture team recently and there are some subtle reasons to do it one way or the other. It mostly comes down to Dependency Injection (as others have noted) and whether or not you truly have control over the creation of the object that you new in the constructor.

In your example, what if your Config class:

a) has non-trivial allocation, such as coming from a pool or factory method.

b) could fail to be allocated. Passing it into the constructor neatly avoids this issue.

c) is actually a subclass of Config.

Passing the object into the constructor gives the most flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

### The answer below is wrong, but I'll keep it for others to learn from it (see below)

In `ExampleA`, you can use the same `Config` instance across multiple classes. However, if there should be only one `Config` instance within the entire application, consider applying the Singleton pattern on `Config` to avoid having multiple instances of `Config`. And if `Config` is a Singleton, you could do the following instead:

```
class ExampleA
{
  private $config;
  public function __construct()
  {
     $this->config = Config->getInstance();
  }
}
$exampleA = new ExampleA();
```

In `ExampleB`, on the other hand, you'll always get a separate instance of `Config` for each instance of `ExampleB`.

Which version you should apply really depends on how the application will handle instances of `Config`:

- if each instance of `ExampleX` should have a separate instance of `Config`, go with `ExampleB`;
- if each instance of `ExampleX` will share one (and only one) instance of `Config`, use `ExampleA with Config Singleton`;
- if instances of `ExampleX` may use different instances of `Config`, stick with `ExampleA`.

### Why converting `Config` into a *Singleton* is wrong:

I must admit that I only learned about the *Singleton* pattern yesterday (reading the *Head First* book of design patterns). Naively I went about and applied it for this example, but as many has pointed out, one way are another (some have been more cryptic and only said "You're doing it wrong!"), this is not a good idea. So, to prevent others from making the same mistake that I just did, here follows a summary of why the *Singleton* pattern can be harmful (based on the comments and what I found out googling it):

1. If `ExampleA` retrieves its own reference to the `Config` instance, the classes will be tightly coupled. There will be no way of having an instance of `ExampleA` to use a different version of `Config` (say some subclass). This is horrible if you want to test `ExampleA` using a mock-up instance of `Config` as there is no way to provide it to `ExampleA`.
2. The premise of there will be one, and only one, instance of `Config` maybe holds *now*, but you cannot always be sure that the same will hold *in the future*. If at some later point it turns out that multiple instances of `Config` will be desirable, there is no way of achieving this without rewriting the code.
3. Even though the one-and-only-one instance of `Config` is maybe true for all eternity, it could happen that you want to be able to use some subclass of `Config` (while still having only one instance). But, since the code directly gets the instance via `getInstance()` of `Config`, which is a `static` method, there is no way to get the subclass. Again, code must be rewritten.
4. The fact that `ExampleA` uses `Config` will be hidden, at least when just viewing the API of `ExampleA`. This may or may not be a bad thing, but personally I feel that this feels like a disadvantage; for instance, when maintaining, there is no simple way of finding out which classes will be affected by changes to `Config` without looking into the implementation of every other class.
5. Even if the fact that `ExampleA` uses a *Singleton* `Config` is not a problem in itself, it may still become a problem from a testing point of view. *Singleton* objects will carry state which will persist until the termination of the application. This can be a problem when running unit tests as you want one test to be isolated from another (i.e. that having executed one test should not affect the outcome of another). To fix this, the *Singleton* object must be destroyed between each test run (potentially having to restart the whole application), which may be time-consuming (not to mention tedious and annoying).

Having said this, I'm glad that I made this mistake *here* and not in the implementation of a real application. In fact, I was actually considering rewriting my latest code to use the *Singleton* pattern for some of the classes. Although I could easily revert the changes (everything is stored in an SVN, of course), I would still have wasted time doing it.

Comment: I would not recommend doing so.. in this way you tightly couple class `ExampleA` and `Config` - which is not a good thing.

Comment: @Paul: That is true. Good catch, didn't think about that.

Comment: I would always recommend against using Singletons for reasons of testability. They are essentially global variables and it's impossible to mock the dependency.

Comment: I would always recommend againts using Singletons for reasons of your doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to couple `ExampleA` to `Config`.  You should do the simplest thing, unless there is a compelling reason to do something more complex.

One reason for decoupling `ExampleA` and `Config` would be to improve the testability of `ExampleA`.  Direct coupling will degrade the testability of `ExampleA` if `Config` has methods that are slow, complex, or rapidly evolving.  For testing, a method is slow if it runs more than a few microseconds.  If all the methods of `Config` are simple and fast, then I would take the simple approach and directly couple `ExampleA` to `Config`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is an example of the Dependency Injection pattern.  A class with an external dependency is handed the dependency by constructor, setter, etc.

This approach results in loosely-coupled code.  Most people think that loose coupling is a good thing, because you can easily substitute the config in the cases where one particular instance of an object needs to be configured differently from the others, you can pass in a mock config object for testing, and so on.

The second approach is closer to the GRASP creator pattern.  In this case, the object creates its own dependencies.  This results in tightly coupled code, this can limit the flexibility of the class and make it more difficult to test.  If you need one instance of a class to have a different dependency from the others, your only option is to subclass it.

It can be the appropriate pattern, however, in cases where the lifespan of the depended-on object is dictated by the lifetime of the dependant object, and where the depended-on object is not used anywhere outside of the object that depends on it.  Normally I'd advise DI to be the default position, but you don't have to rule out the other approach entirely as long as you're aware of its consequences.

Answer (score 0):

If your class doesn't expose the `$config` to external classes, then I'd create it inside the constructor.  This way, you're keeping your internal state private.

If the `$config` requires requires its own internal state to be set properly (e.g., needs a database connection or some internal fields initialized) before use, then it makes sense to defer the initialization to some external code (possibly a factory class) and inject it in the constructor.  Or, as others have pointed out, if it needs to be shared among other objects.

Answer (score 0):

**ExampleA is decoupled** from concrete class Config **which is good**, provided object received if not of type Config but the type of an abstract superclass of Config.

**ExampleB is strongly** coupled to concrete class Config **which is bad**.

Instantiating an object creates a strong coupling between classes. It should be done in a Factory class.